# Extracting a jar from the currently running jar

Tags: java, jar, extract

I'm trying to extract 2 jar files from the currently running jar however they always end up at 2kb even though their sizes are 104kb and 1.7m, Heres what I've got

```
public static boolean extractFromJar(String fileName, String dest) {
    if (Configuration.getRunningJarPath() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    File file = new File(dest + fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        file.mkdir();
        return false;
    }
    try {
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(Configuration.getRunningJarPath());
        Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jar.entries();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(jar.getInputStream(je));
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file));
            copyInputStream(in, out);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Methods.debug(e);
        return false;
    }
}

private final static void copyInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        out.write(in.read());
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work better then relying on InputStream.available() method:

```
private final static void copyInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
    int n;
    while ((n = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
        out.write(buff, 0, n);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`available()` method is not reliable to read data as it is just an estimate, as per its documentation.
You need to depend on `read()` method until read a non -ve.

```
byte[] contentBytes = new byte[ 4096 ];  
int bytesRead = -1;
while ( ( bytesRead = inputStream.read( contentBytes ) ) > 0 )   
{   
    out.write( contentBytes, 0, bytesRead );  
} // while available
```

You can go through a discussion on what the problems with `available()` is at [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874713/java-read-from-inputstream-doesnt-always-read-the-same-amount-of-data).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about extracting jars, but every jar is actually a zip file, so you can try unzip it.

you can findout about unziping in java here:
[How to unzip files recursively in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java)